# Why hexadecimal to decimal string output different using intval and hexdec build in function in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, hex

I am using two ways to convert a hexadecimal string to decimal. Using intval function in which I am passing 16 base as the second parameter to convert the hexa decimal string in decimal. same thing I am doing using hexdec built-in function. Both returning different answer.

May I know the reason behind these two function's output?

```
$a = 'efdebd76';
echo 'intvar : '. intval($a,16);
echo '<br/>';
echo 'hexdec : '.hexdec($a);
```

> Output
>
> intvar : 2147483647
>
> hexdec : 4024352118

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from php manual about "intval" function:

> **Return Values:**
>   The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is 9223372036854775807.

so I guess you run intval on 32 bit system because it return you the value 2147483647, and the value of 0xefdebd76 is bigger than the maximum Integer value.
in hex_string, it's seems that it not limited by the system you execute this function.

Comment: I tested in the 64-bit system and getting this issue.

Comment: Yes, I print PHP version architecture 32 bit and getting 2147483647 but when I tested in 64 bit then getting actual value 4024352118. So you are correct and thanks for solving this issue.

Comment: you can add your php version? and if it 32 bit version or 64 bit?  also the OS version and the cpu?